# Routing error in rails using current_page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to add some conditional open graph tags to my app, using `current_page`, but I'm getting a routing error:

This is what I get on `rake routes`

```
product GET    /products/:id(.:format)    {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products"}
```

And this is in my partial:

```
<% if current_page?(:controller => 'products', :action => 'show') %>
...
<% end %>
```

But I get:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"products", :action=>"show"}
```

I've tried using `product` and `products` but neither seems to work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass the id as well:

```
<% if current_page?(:controller => 'products', :action => 'show', :id => params[:id]) %>
```

**UPDATE:**

But, however, this implementation assumes that the pages that render this partial have id as a param. If they do not, it's better to use a local variable for that.

```
render :partial => 'blah_blah', :locals => {:id_for_route_verification => params[:id] || 0}
```

and in the partial use the new local variable

```
<% if current_page?(:controller => 'products', :action => 'show', :id => id_for_route_verification) %>
```

I know this is kinda hacky. But, in the first place, you should consider using `content_for` to render content inside partial conditionally rather than going by `current_page?` approach

Comment: So, I thought this was the answer -- but it introduced a bug where any page that didn't match or have `params[:id]` in the URL threw a 404 not found error.